# How does a manifest file work in .NET apps?

Tags: .net

I was using ANTS Profiler 4 and started it without admin rights in Vista. The app threw a dialog box asking whether I want to create a manifest file so that the application always launches with admin rights (it needs it to function fully).

How would a manifest file look like? Will it persist something like "AdminRights = true", which means launch with admin rights, so everytimne the application opens, it will look at this file and if the value is "AdminRights = true", as above, then launch with admin rights (a function dependent on the Windows SDK? Please correct).

How would this work? What code/file structure is involved?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let ANTS Profiler generates a sample for you.

Manifest file is very useful on Windows Vista and 7.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/vistabridge.aspx